# $n$th derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives

$f(x)=x \, \ln(x+1)$;  calculate $f^{(n)}(x).$

I know the first derivative is easy, $f'(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x}+\ln(x+1).$
I can't get the $n$th derivative.

Comment: Compute the second and third derivatives, things will clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it seems that your original function should have been $$f(x)= x\ln(x+1)$$ so that you have $$ f'(x)=\ln(x+1)+\dfrac{x}{1+x}$$

Now your second derivative is $$ f''(x) =(1+x)^{-1} +(1+x)^{-2}$$

$$ f'''(x)= -(1+x)^{-2} -2(1+x)^{-3}$$

$$ f^{(4)} = 2(1+x)^{-3} +6(1+x)^{-4}$$
 You can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

$f'(x)$ can be written  $$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}+\ln(x+1).$$

Can you continue from this?